# CustomListener's onTestFailure not ran when test fails

Tags: testng

I am trying to get TestNG to do something when test fails using custom listener. I obtain TestNG instance with `getDefault` and I add my custom listener to it. When the test fails, `onTestFailure` never gets executed. Any ideas what's wrong? I guess that I am just understanding this wrong and it's not even supposed to work this way. I have tried running tests using Intellij IDEA and using mvn test.

---

```
public class CustomListener extends TestListenerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult testResult) {
        System.out.println("Test Failed!!!");
    }
}
```

---

```
public class TestClass {

    private TestNG testNG;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        testNG = TestNG.getDefault();
        testNG.addListener(new CustomListener());

        Assert.assertFalse("Should have been false..", true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify your listener via [testng.xml, Java](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#listeners-testng-xml), or [the ServiceLoader class](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#listeners-service-loader).

Comment: So only these work? So there is really no easy way to add custom listener in code without annotations, which makes it impossible to add parameters to CustomListener?

Comment: No, not at all but that is a different question. :-) If you want to add a listener without using a default constructor then you can [run TestNG programmatically](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically) (`TestNG.getDefault()` is deprecated) or use [dependency injection](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependency-injection). I recommend the latter.

Comment: And by [run TestNG programmatically](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically) I mean creating a new `TestNG` instance, adding the listener(s), adding the tests you want to run, and then running the tests all with that instance (and not trying to add listeners to the already running TestNG instance).

Comment: I just tried and it turns out TestNG does not currently support dependency injection for listeners so it looks like you'll have to run TestNG programmatically but it would probably be easier to use system properties or something else to inject your values yourself. You're call.

Comment: Yes, my question was meant to be if it's possible to add listener to already running TestNG instance. I know getDefault is deprecated but it works and it has been deprecated for very long time. Too bad if it's not possible to add listener to already existing TestNG instance though. Thanks for your help.